# Excel Exception Report - Creating all combinations of two columns and removing those that already exist

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make an exception report in Excel that can be used for various different spreadsheets. The idea is that the user can input two variables that indicate which two columns to compare. Then, all of the combinations of those two columns will be created. Finally, this new list will be compared to the existing list and all combinations that already exist will be removed from the produced exception report.

> **Example:** We have Column A which is "apples, pears, apples, pears, oranges"
>   and Column B which is "1, 2, 2, 3, 1"
>
> If we combine these two columns we get Apples1, Pears2, Apples2,
>   Pears3, Oranges1. Now, each of Column A should have a pair with each
>   of Column B. Basically, every possible combination should exist. So we
>   are missing Apples3, Pears 1, and Oranges2 & 3. These are the pairs
>   that would fill the exception report (in separate columns).

In my spreadsheet I already have a few macros in place that can get me the first step - a list of every single possible combination (that should exist within the system). However, I am having a hard time figuring out a VBA solution to now removing every single result in this list that already exists within the the original list (pulled from our system).

Here are the macros:

First one is to copy the two columns and paste them onto another sheet (to keep raw data untouched). Then it removes duplicates in each column.

```
Sub CopyandRemoveDup()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'Copy Column 1
    Sheets("Raw Data").Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Inputs & Outputs").Range("C1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'Need to clean this up
    Sheets("Inputs & Outputs").Columns("C:C").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo


'Copy Column 2

    Sheets("Raw Data").Columns("B:B").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Inputs & Outputs").Range("D1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'Need to clean this up
    Sheets("Inputs & Outputs").Columns("D:D").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Be careful without headers
    Sheets("Inputs & Outputs").Range("C1:D1").Delete

End Sub
```

This next macros actually create the new list with all of the possible combinations from the pasted columns in the previous macro

```
Sub ListCombinations()

Dim col As New Collection
Dim c As Range, sht As Worksheet, res
Dim i As Long, arr, numCols As Long

    Sheets("Inputs & Outputs").Select
    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    For Each c In sht.Range("C1:D1").Cells
        col.Add Application.Transpose(sht.Range(c, c.End(xlDown)))
        numCols = numCols + 1
    Next c

    res = Combine(col, "~~")

    For i = 0 To UBound(res)
        arr = Split(res(i), "~~")
        sht.Range("H1").Offset(i, 0).Resize(1, numCols) = arr
    Next i

End Sub


'create combinations from a collection of string arrays
Function Combine(col As Collection, SEP As String) As String()

    Dim rv() As String
    Dim pos() As Long, lengths() As Long, lbs() As Long, ubs() As Long
    Dim t As Long, i As Long, n As Long, ub As Long
    Dim numIn As Long, s As String, r As Long

    numIn = col.Count
    ReDim pos(1 To numIn)
    ReDim lbs(1 To numIn)
    ReDim ubs(1 To numIn)
    ReDim lengths(1 To numIn)
    t = 0
    For i = 1 To numIn  'calculate # of combinations, and cache bounds/lengths
        lbs(i) = LBound(col(i))
        ubs(i) = UBound(col(i))
        lengths(i) = (ubs(i) - lbs(i)) + 1
        pos(i) = lbs(i)
        t = IIf(t = 0, lengths(i), t * lengths(i))
    Next i
    ReDim rv(0 To t - 1) 'resize destination array

    For n = 0 To (t - 1)
        s = ""
        For i = 1 To numIn
            s = s & IIf(Len(s) > 0, SEP, "") & col(i)(pos(i)) 'build the string
        Next i
        rv(n) = s

        For i = numIn To 1 Step -1
            If pos(i) <> ubs(i) Then   'Not done all of this array yet...
                pos(i) = pos(i) + 1    'Increment array index
                For r = i + 1 To numIn 'Reset all the indexes
                    pos(r) = lbs(r)    '   of the later arrays
                Next r
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    Next n

    Combine = rv
End Function
```

How would I compare the list in Columns("C:D") to the one in Columns ("H:I") and remove matches from Columns ("H:I") so that only the exceptions are showing?

Comment: In essence, you could loop through each item in C:D, check for a match in H:I (using find or match or countif) and if there is a match delete the two cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SJR's advice this is what I came up with::

```
Sub HTH()

    With Range("H1", Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp)).Offset(, 2)
        .Formula = "=COUNTIFS('Raw Data'!$A:$A,H1,'Raw Data'!$B:$B,I1)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub




Sub DeleteRowBasedOnCriteria()
Dim RowToTest As Long

For RowToTest = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1

With Cells(RowToTest, 3)
    If .Value = "1" _
    Then _
    Rows(RowToTest).EntireRow.Delete
End With

Next RowToTest
```

Thanks!